# Changing gzip compression level on Azure APIM?

Tags: azure-api-management

Working on a scenario where transfer size really matters.

Is there any way to specify in the APIM configuration what gzip compression level to use for the response?

Note that I already know how to enable gzip of the response. What I want is to specify the gzip compression level to use (0-9).

Answer (score 0):

Use `set-header` policy to set desired value for `Content-Encoding` header on the response in the `outbound` section, and APIM will compress the payload, for example:

```
<outbound>
  <set-header name="Content-Encoding" exist-action="override">
    <value>gzip</value>
  </set-header>
</outbound>
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to enable gzip. What I'm asking is whether it's possible to specify what gzip compression level to use (0-9). This cannot be controlled by HTTP headers so, if possible, should be somewhere in the APIM policies or other config.

Comment: Alas that is not possible at the moment. Perhaps a feature could be introduced in future. Feel free to upvote or file feature request: https://aka.ms/apimwish